# Component not re-rendering on useState array change

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a favorite button on the 'tweet' card that I show on the `FeedScreen.js`.

```js
~~~~~~~~~ IMPORTS SNIP ~~~~~~~~~

function FeedScreen(props) {
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState([]);
  const [favorites, setFavorite] = useState([]);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadFeed(0, 4);
  }, []);

  const loadFeed = async (last_id = 0, limit = 1) => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    const response = await tweetsApi.getTweets(last_id, limit);
    if (response.ok) {
      setFeed(response.data["data"].concat(feed));
    } else {
      console.log(response.problem);
    }
    setRefreshing(false);
  };

  const handleBookmark = async (item_id) => {
    const response = await tweetsApi.toggleBookmark(item_id);
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("ok response");
      setFavorite(favorites.concat(item_id));
// I've tried this as well
// setFavorite([...favorites].concat(item_id));
// but in vain
      console.log(favorites);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Screen style={styles.screen}>
      <FlatList
        data={feed}
        keyExtractor={(tweet) => {
          return tweet.id.toString();
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~
            <CardFooter
              style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}
              item={item}
              onPress={handleBookmark}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={() => {
          loadFeed(feed[0]["id"], 2);
        }}
      />
    </Screen>
  );
}

~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~
```

And here's the `CardFooter.js` :

```js
~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~

function CardFooter({ item, onPress }) {
  return (
      <View style={styles.bookmark}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            return onPress(item.id);
          }}
        >
          {item.bookmarked && (
            <FontAwesome name="bookmark" size={24} color="red" />
          )}
          {!item.bookmarked && (
            <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={24} color="black" />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
export default CardFooter;
~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~
```

However the component doesn't seem to re render.
I've looked at these :

1. [react-component-not-re-rendering-after-using-usestate-hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441738/react-component-not-re-rendering-after-using-usestate-hook)
2. Similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856176/ui-not-re-rendering-on-state-update-using-react-hooks-and-form-submission)
3. [Another one 17 days back - why-usestate-is-not-re-rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265326/why-usestate-is-not-re-rendering)
4. [usestate-not-re-rendering-when-updating-nested-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033178/usestate-not-re-rendering-when-updating-nested-object)

All of these and similar other ones, each one of them point to the fact that the a new array should be created so that react re-renders it.

### Update

#### console.log output

yes the `console.log` is printing the array, although one value previous. That's because `useState` is async so it isn't printing the realtime array. So, when the second time this is called, it would show one `item_id` ( the previous one ) added to `favorites`

Comment: Did you `console.log()` your response to see if data was indeed returned?

Comment: what is the console.log(favorites) showing?

Comment: @Ross updated the question,with `console.log` output

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by managing the **state in the component itself**.

Not sure if this is 'the proper way' to do this, but read [here (how-to-add-a-simple-toggle-function-in-react-native)](https://reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-add-a-simple-toggle-function-in-react-native/)  that this is how you can do this.

So, now the bookmark component gets its response from the top level component ( `FeedScreen.js` ) :

```js
const handleBookmark = async (item_id) => {
    const response = await tweetsApi.toggleBookmark(item_id);
    if (response.ok) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

And changing the `CardFooter.js` i.e. where the bookmark component resides.

```js
function CardFooter({ item, onPress }) {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(item.bookmarked);
  return (
      <View style={styles.bookmark}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={async () => {
            let response = await onPress(item.id);
            if (response) {
              setFavorite(!favorite);
            } else {
              alert("Some error occurred");
            }
          }}
        >
          {favorite && <FontAwesome name="bookmark" size={24} color="red" />}
          {!favorite && (
            <FontAwesome5 name="bookmark" size={24} color="black" />
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

#### Concerns

I am a bit concerned about handling the response in this component.

Should I handle the `async` operation in the bottom component ?